# HTC software update causes phone to reboot in the TWRP recovery mode and does not update. How to fix it?

Tags: updates, rooting, recovery-mode, htc-one, twrp

I just rooted my HTC One (M7) according to [LINK](http://htconeroot.com/htc-one-root/how-to-root-htc-one-windowsmaclinux/). It is s-on, and TWRP (teamwin) recovery is flashed.Rooting is successful and everything seems fine. Except:

When I go in the "setting, about, update software" in the phone, it downloads the HTC updates. But when it tries to run the downloaded updates, it reboots, and it goes into "recovery" mode, where TWRP shows up. What should I do from there? 
I choose system reboot from TWRP and it phone is up as normal, but the updates are still waiting to be run.

How should I apply updates?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official OTA's from HTC could only be installed if you posses the stock recovery.
You can download the right one for you from XDA [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2545227).
When you have downloaded it you can just flash it by typing this (with your phone connected in fastboot mode):

`fastboot flash recovery path/to/recovery.img`

Disclaimer: Probably the update won't work if you have a custom ROM installed on it (custom ROMs sometimes have different packages that the OTA will corrupt). If you want to update via OTA you should first install a stock HTC ROM too.

Answer (score 1):

Manufacturer OTAs can only be flashed using the recovery that came with your device, which is (more often than not) 3e recovery.

I would recommend that you find a stock recovery.img, `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`, then apply the OTA.

Comment: Thanks.
Sorry it might be very naive question, I am newbie: Now that my phone is rooted, can I uninstall TWRP recovery and go back to original recovery while keeping the phone rooted?

Comment: @cybergeek654 Yes, changing the recovery doesn't affect whether the device is rooted, but the update will probably either unroot or won't apply while the device is rooted.

Comment: But it (updating OTA while rooted) won't damage my phone, right? If so, I will try it, if it does not work, I will unroot it as well.